# Indefinite integral $\int \Phi(x^2) \cdot \phi(x) \,dx$

Tags: probability, integration, indefinite-integrals

Let $\Phi(x)$ be the standard normal CDF, and $\phi(x)$ be the PDF. Any ideas on how to evaluate the indefinite integral
$$\int \Phi(x^2) \cdot \phi(x) \,dx$$

I tried integration by parts, and got the following form:
$$\int \Phi(x) \cdot \phi(x^2)\cdot x \,dx.$$

Also tried simple substitutions, which didn't help.

Comment: It doesn't look to me that $\text{Erf}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)e^{-x^2/2}$ has an elementary antiderivative. Can you provide a bit more context? What is the origin of this problem?

Comment: I second the previous comment. Is there any motivation for you to think there's a closed form for this indefinite integral?